# Etsy Staggered gridview android smoothScrollToPosition

Tags: android, gridview, smooth-scrolling, staggered-gridview

I have to implement a smoothScrollToPosition with Eatsy Staggered gridview but the Gridview method doesn't work. How can I do a method that simulate the smooth scroll to a specific cell?

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(*myCondition*){

                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

                    }

                }

}
```

With standard GridView smoothScrollToPosition works fine, not works with Staggered.

```
gridView.setSelection(position);
```

not work correctly, the cells change their position and if I scroll the grid manually restore their correct position (with standard grid view works fine, so I think the problem isn't my code but the library)

Comment: Show yore investigation and code samples.

Comment: edited, I have added only the ui method

Comment: Did u solved the problem? I need to scroll the staggered gridview to a specific position. Please let me know.....

Comment: smoothScrollToPosition method is not supported by Eatsy Staggered gridview: https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid/issues/71#issuecomment-39676186

Comment: I put the gridView into a scrollView and calculated the top position for each cell. You have to calculate the gridview's height using ViewTreeObserver. SmoothScrollToPosition of scrollview works fine. It's not a good solution but the only I found and works fine for me. I'll post the code as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Late response but I think you'd be better off using RecyclerView with StaggeredManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html